# One class implements from two different interfaces in Java

Tags: java, class, interface

I have two classes that implements from two interfaces.
Here is my interfaces:

```
interface Identifiable {

     int getId();

}
```

```
interface Greetable {
    String helloMessage();
    String byeMessage();    
}
```

Here is my classes:

```
public class Lecturer implements Greetable, Identifiable {

    private int employeeId;
    private String name;
    private String title;

    @Override
    public String helloMessage() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String byeMessage() {
        return title;
    }   

}
```

```
public class Student implements Greetable, Identifiable {

    private char examScore;

    @Override
    public String helloMessage() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    @Override
    public String byeMessage() {
        return "Whats up";
    }   


}
```

I get the error from the classes that it has to abstract the methods from the interfaces? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

Non-abstract classes are required to create concrete versions of any methods found in any interfaces that they're implementing, and while your classes implement concrete versions of one of the interface, the Greetable interface, you're not implementing all the methods of both interfaces, here the `public int getId()` method from the Identifiable interface is missing from both classes.

Solution: give both classes an int id field as well as the `getId()` method that returns the value held by this field.

e.g. for Student,

```
public class Student implements Greetable, Identifiable {

    private char examScore;
    private int id;  // **** your classes will need this field ****

    // need to set the ID somehow, either with a setter or a constructor
    public Student(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String helloMessage() {
        return "Hi";
    }

    @Override
    public String byeMessage() {
        return "Whats up";
    }

    @Override  // **************** add this method to return the value held by id ******
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You havent implemeted the `getId()` method in `Identifiable`. If you are not implementing that method you need to make the `Lecturer`  and `Student` as abstract or you need to implement the `getId()` method in both the classes.

In your case I think you will need to create instances of the `Student` and `Lecturer`. If so then you cannot make them as abstract, as abstract class instances cannot be created. So better implement the `getId()` in both the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You define to implement both interfaces, but you only implemented the methods of the second interface.
So you have to implement the method getId() in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student` and `Lecturer` classes MUST implement both `Greetable`, `Identifiable` `interface` methods, otherwise they need to be declared as `abstract` classes i.e., you are missing `getId()` from `Identifiable` `interface`, which is causing the issues, corrected code below.

**Lecturer class:**

```
public class Lecturer implements Greetable, Identifiable {
    int getId() {
       return employeeId;
    }

   //all other existing methods
}
```

**Student class:**

```
public class Student implements Greetable, Identifiable {
        int getId() {
           return studentId;
        }

       //all other existing methods
    }
```

You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)